# The embed in my search command isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, distube

In this `search` command, the `for in` loop is not adding the fields to the embed. When I use the command, I get the name and description, which I defined while creating the embed. But I do not get the fields which I add in the `for in` loop.

Here is an image of what is returned, just in case it helps answer my question:

[image: An image of what the command returns]

**My `search` command code:**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'search',
    description: 'Searches for a song and returns the results.',
  options: [
    {
      name: 'search_term',
      description: 'The song to search for.',
      type: 'STRING',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'limit',
      type: 'INTEGER',
      description: 'Number of results to return.',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'type',
      type: 'STRING',
      description: 'The type of search result.',
      required: true,
      choices: [{
        name: 'Video',
        value: 'video'
      },
      {
        name: 'Playlist',
        value: 'playlist'
      }]
    }
  ],
    async execute(interaction) {
    const query = await interaction.options.getString('search_term')
    const limit = await interaction.options.getInteger('limit')
    const type = await interaction.options.getString('type')

    let type2 = 'x'
    if (type === 'video') type2 = 'Video'
    else if (type === 'playlist') type2 = 'Playlist'

    let results = await interaction.client.distube.search(query, { limit: limit, type: type })

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('search')
    .setDescription('Searches for a song and returns the results.')

    for (const result in results) {
      if (result.type === 'video') {
        embed.addFields({
          name :result.name, 
          value: `ID: ${result.id}\nType: ${type2}\nURL: ${result.url}\nViews: ${result.views}\nDuration: ${result.formattedDuration}\nLive: ${result.isLive}`, 
          inline: true})
      }
      else if (result.type === 'playlist') {
        embed.addFields({
          name: result.name, 
          value: `ID: ${result.id}\nType: ${type2}\nURL: ${result.url}\nViews: ${result.views}`,
          inline: true})
      }
    }

    await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]})
    

    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: Use `for of` instead of `for in`

Difference between the 2:

The for...of statement creates a loop **iterating over iterable objects**, including: built-in `String`, `Array`, array-like objects (e.g., arguments or `NodeList`), `TypedArray`, `Map`, `Set`

The for...in statement **iterates over all enumerable properties** of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.

For more information:

`for of`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

`for in`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `embed.addField(...)` or to pass an array to `embed.addFields([...])`.

[`<MessageEmbed>.addFields()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) takes an array as an input.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtSiOXctALRijVjciJCqx511y343?e=K2047V

It does, here's an image @Milo Moisson